# ECHO in an ECHO in an IF

Tags: php, echo

Config.php:

```
<?php
$sidebars = 'TRUE';
$sidebar_left = '<font color="GREEN">Hoejhus9 1#</font>'; 
$sidebar_right = 'KinJacob - Ejer';
?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
if ($sidebars == "TRUE") {
    echo '
    <div class="sidebar">
    <h1><center>Status</center></h1>
    <h3><center>CS:S</center></h3>
    '.echo $sidebar_left.'
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_2">
    <h1><center>Admins</center></h1>
    '.echo $sidebar_right.'
    </div>';
}
?>
```

This does not work at all. It is not even displaying the page? Just white!
And if I try to use a `print` instead of `echo` it shows "1" at the right place and then the text at a whole diffrent page? What should I do?

Comment: `echo 'string'.$variable.'another string';`. This is like first day stuff while learning how to program with PHP. Try picking up a PHP tutorial somewhere and go through it.

Answer (score 2):

One echo statement is all you need:

```
echo '
<div class="sidebar">
<h1><center>Status</center></h1>
<h3><center>CS:S</center></h3>
'.$sidebar_left.'
</div>
<div class="sidebar_2">
<h1><center>Admins</center></h1>
'.$sidebar_right.'
</div>';
```

Comment: Wow that is amazing, thank you so much... I didnt even think of it :)

Comment: I'd be inclined to exit out of PHP mode, and render most of that in HTML. Storing chunks of HTML in echo statements hides the structure of the document from the browser, and worsens syntax colouration.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use boolean values as a string. Remove extra `echo` when concat strings. so:

```
$sidebars = true;
          //^
$sidebar_left = '<font color="GREEN">Hoejhus9 1#</font>'; 
$sidebar_right = 'KinJacob - Ejer';

include 'config.php';
if ($sidebars == true) {
               //^
    echo '
        <div class="sidebar">
        <h1><center>Status</center></h1>
        <h3><center>CS:S</center></h3>
        ' . $sidebar_left . '
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar_2">
        <h1><center>Admins</center></h1>
        ' . $sidebar_right . '
        </div>
    ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your web host has PHP shorthand enabled you could do it like this, you can close and reopen the PHP tag and use the shorthand `<?=` and `?>` to echo values

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
if ($sidebars == TRUE){
?>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h1><center>Status</center></h1>
        <h3><center>CS:S</center></h3>
        <?=$sidebar_left?>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar_2">
        <h1><center>Admins</center></h1>
        <?=$sidebar_right?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```